How to format columns inside a Table row (here third)?
I want a Table that looks like this, 
The code that I use in Overleaf is this below,
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h!] 
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \textbf{Metrices} & \textbf{UTL} & \textbf{BEC} & \textbf{CTH} & \textbf{IWW} \\ 
    \hline
    \textbf{Ge Fraction (in D4R)} & 12 & 24 & 16 & 4 \\ 
    \hline
    \textbf{Total CN (Ge-Ge)} & 28 & 20 & 9 & 7 \\ 
    \hline
    \hspace{0.6cm} \newline \textbf{D4R,} & 12, & 24, & 16,  &  4, \\ 
    \textbf{Occu Freq} \newline \textbf{Adj,} & 15, & 43, & 5, & 10, \\ \hspace{0.6cm}
    \newline \textbf{  Frw} & 20 & 20 & 8 & 7 \\ 
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}

The result of this looks like this, 
Please suggest how to align the D4R, Adj, and Frw in the same way as intended. Thanks.

You could split your first column in two and use \multicolumn for the first three rows. By the way, why are you using \newline in several places in the big cell?

You could also use a {tabular} for that cell. Please also have a look at the booktabs pacakge.

Although not the most elegant solution, I used \multicolumn.
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h] 
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|cl|c|c|c|c|} \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Metrices}} & \textbf{UTL} & \textbf{BEC} & \textbf{CTH} & \textbf{IWW} \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Ge Fraction (in D4R)}} & 12 & 24 & 16 & 4 \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Total CN (Ge-Ge)}} & 28 & 20 & 9 & 7 \\ \hline
        & \textbf{D4R,} & 12, & 24, & 16,  &  4, \\ 
        \textbf{Occu Freq} & \textbf{Adj,} & 15, & 43, & 5, & 10, \\
        & \textbf{Frw} & 20 & 20 & 8 & 7 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}



You can use a “phantom”. I measure the text and locally define a command that leaves the precise amount of space.
However, I'd prefer the style of the second table; with more space available you can avoid ugly abbreviations such as “Occu Freq” (I didn't dare to expand it, though).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}% for the second realization

\newlength{\indranillength} % a scratch length for your needs

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\settowidth{\indranillength}{\textbf{Occu Freq }}
\newcommand{\OF}{\hspace{\indranillength}}

\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|}\hline
\textbf{Metrics} & \textbf{UTL} & \textbf{BEC} & \textbf{CTH} & \textbf{IWW} \\ \hline
\textbf{Ge Fraction (in D4R)} & 12 & 24 & 16 &  4 \\ \hline
\textbf{Total CN (Ge-Ge)}     & 28 & 20 &  9 &  7 \\ \hline
\OF       \textbf{D4R}        & 12 & 24 & 16 &  4 \\ 
\textbf{Occu Freq Adj}        & 15 & 43 &  5 & 10 \\
\OF       \textbf{Frw}        & 20 & 20 &  8 &  7 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\caption{A caged table, difficult to read}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{@{}lcccc@{}}
\toprule
Metrics & UTL & BEC & CTH & IWW \\
\midrule
Ge Fraction (in D4R) & 12 & 24 & 16 &  4 \\
Total CN (Ge-Ge)     & 28 & 20 &  9 &  7 \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{5}{@{}l@{}}{\itshape Occu Freq} \\
D4R                  & 12 & 24 & 16 &  4 \\ 
Adj                  & 15 & 43 &  5 & 10 \\
Frw                  & 20 & 20 &  8 &  7 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{An open look table, easier to read}
\end{table}

\end{document}

I removed the commas, which I think aren't really useful.


With {NiceTabular} of nicematrix. However, I recommend in the style and spirit of booktabs (seed egreg's answer).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

\begin{NiceTabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|}[,hlines={1,2,3,4,7},ampersand-in-blocks]
Metrics & UTL & BEC & CTH & IWW \\
Ge fraction (in D4R) & 12 & 24 & 16 & 4 \\
Total CN (Ge-Ge) & 28 & 20 & 9 & 7 \\
\Block[l]{}{&D4R} & 12 & 24 & 16 & 4 \\
\Block[l]{}{Occu Freq&Adj} & 25 & 43 & 5 & 10 \\
\Block[l]{}{&Frw} & 20 & 20 & 8 & 7 \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}


